# AWStats Extra Section Column Width

Tags: html, css, width, awstats

Thanks for taking the time to help.  I created an extra section report in awstats and everything works perfectly.  However, I have a row with a very long entry.
Example:  "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
This entry makes the table a different size than all the rest of the tables in the report.

So my question is:
Can I adjust the column width of the extra section tables in awstats.pl so that it is fixed for all extra sections?  Or, can I set a default width for the tables?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  I found the answer.

In awstats.pl, lines 930 and 932 you must add "word-wrap:break-word; max-width: 500px;" to the "th" and "td" styles.

Examples:

`th              { border-color: #$color_TableBorder; border-left-width: 0px; border-right-width: 1px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 1px; padding: 1px 2px 1px 1px; font: 11px verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; color: #$color_titletext; word-wrap:break-word; max-width: 500px; }`

`td              { border-color: #$color_TableBorder; border-left-width: 0px; border-right-width: 1px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 1px; font: 11px verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; color: #$color_text; word-wrap:break-word; max-width: 500px;  }`